# Apache Airflow, Custom Trigger logs not showing up

Tags: python, airflow

I'm learning about Apache Airflow, and have implemented a simple custom Sensor and Trigger

```
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.triggers.temporal import TimeDeltaTrigger
from triggers.example_trigger import ExampleTrigger


class ExampleSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def execute(self, context):
        self.defer(trigger=ExampleTrigger(), method_name="execute_complete")

    def execute_complete(self, context, event=None):
        print(f"{type(event)} - {event}")
        context["ti"].xcom_push(key="approved", value=event)
        # We have no more work to do here. Mark as complete.
        return
```

```
from typing import Any, Tuple, Dict
import asyncio
import logging
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.triggers.temporal import TimeDeltaTrigger
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.triggers.base import BaseTrigger, TriggerEvent


class ExampleTrigger(BaseTrigger):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def serialize(self) -> Tuple[str, Dict[str, int]]:
        return ("triggers.example_trigger.ExampleTrigger", {})

    async def run(self):

        var_val = str(Variable.get("approval")).lower().strip()
        logging.info(f"Approval was: {var_val}")

        while var_val != "true" and var_val != "false":
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            var_val = str(Variable.get("approval")).lower().strip()
            logging.info(f"Approval was: {var_val}")


        yield TriggerEvent(var_val == "true")
```

This is all working fine, but for some reason the logging just in the Trigger is not working

```
logging.info(f"Approval was: {var_val}")
```

Here are the logs for the `ExampleSensor`

```
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1300} INFO - Executing <Task(ExampleSensor): approval_sensor> on 2023-03-03 15:17:26.006014+00:00
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 412 to run task
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'example_flow', 'approval_sensor', 'manual__2023-03-03T15:17:26.006014+00:00', '--job-id', '36', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/example_flow.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp2p2l6n8u']
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 36: Subtask approval_sensor
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {task_command.py:388} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_flow.approval_sensor manual__2023-03-03T15:17:26.006014+00:00 [running]> on host 44f3eeacb622
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - <class 'bool'> - False
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1323} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=example_flow, task_id=approval_sensor, execution_date=20230303T151726, start_date=20230303T151726, end_date=20230303T151730
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {local_task_job.py:208} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-03-03, 15:17:30 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2578} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Is there something special that needs to be done in order to get the logs from the Trigger to show up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running standalone Airflow? In that case logs from processes running in the Triggerer should show up in the console together with logs from the webserver and scheduler. Some background: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/24832

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary import logging on Trigger. The BaseTrigger class inherits from LoggingMixin that provide you a logger so you can use `self.log.info` instead of `logging.info`.

On the other hand, I have a similar problem. In my case the log returned in 'execute_complete' are shown in webserver only when logging_level is set to DEBUG in airflow.cfg. When I set logging_level to INFO although I use info level severity the logs are stopped when the task is deferred. Someone have this problem? Could this be a bug?.